# Starling Juggler Loop

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am building a simple game with a few animations and I am having a problem with a loop extended from starling.

My code uses sprite sheets and texture atlas to fetch the animation sprites but when I add

```
anim.loop = false
```

the animation doesn't play at all. My code looks like:

```
anim = new MovieClip(Assets.getAtlasDuck().getTextures("duck_"), 20);
anim.loop = false;
starling.core.Starling.juggler.add(anim);
this.addChild(anim);
```

if I remove the loop the animation plays but loops. If I add:

```
anim.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.COMPLETE, duckComplete);
```

the animation doesn't play. the duckComplete function just removes the animation from the juggler.

I want the animation to play once and then stop. Even adding:

```
anim.play();
```

doesn't play the animation with the event listener or the loop = false.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the MovieClip with a loop property set to false to the Juggler you have to control the clip manually using these MovieClip functions:

```
anim.play();
anim.pause();
anim.stop();
```

[Starling Documentation](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/)

Comment: upvote for right answer, although the link isn't really helpful is it?

Comment: oh, haha.  i didn't post the link to the documentation to be a douche, although now i see it could easily be misread and does look kinda douchey.  i included it since i think it's an essential resource for anyone using Starling to have. :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Even if I don't add the play() command the animation still plays but as soon as I add the loop = false or the COMPLETE event listener the animation doesn't play at all. I thought I was missing something in the documentation

Comment: The animation is in a separate class but that shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: OK, seems to work when the mc is directly on the stage and not in a separate class file.